# ASP.NET MVC4 Model Not Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a very simple ASP.NET MVC4 page. It's rendering an edit form for the CustomerModel. The form displays correctly, but when I hit edit and post back, the model isn't being bound. Instead, all the properties of the CustomerModel are left at their defaults. Note that the correct controller method *is* being invoked, so that's not the issue.

I can see the form values with matching names to the model properties (Id, Name, Description), but the model doesn't have them set.

Ideas?

Here is the model:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    [Required] 
    public Guid Id;

    [Required]
    public string Name;

    [Required]
    public string Description;
}
```

And here is the relevant controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CustomerModel customerModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //...Do stuff

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customerModel);
    }
```

Finally, here is a screen shot of the form collection with the populated values:

[image]

Comment: I don't see your AntiForgeryToken in there.

Comment: Where do you expect to see it? I have it in the view and I have the validate attribute on the method.

Comment: It has to be in your form, not just in your view.  It has to be among the submitted form collection values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your model has public fields but not public properties, these are not the same.

Change to:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    [Required] 
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

The default MVC model binder will work with properties, not fields.

More about this here - http://rightbrainleft.net/2011/02/default-mvc-model-binder-doesnt-like-fields/

Comment: Ha! That was it. Probably never would have caught that. Thanks!